# C# Playfair Cipher

Tags: c#

What i'm trying to do is take a key and message and combine the two. Remove the duplicate letters and construct a 2d 5x5 array from the combined strings.
Then replace the message characters with the inverse location of the letters in the 2d array. So if the letter A is at position 2,3, i would replace that letter with the letter at position 3,2.

I've no clue how to do this. I've been searching on here and reddit and codeproject and general google inquiries. I've been down many paths and nothing has been successful. I just don't know how to do it.

```
    // array of the alphabet for replacing string letters
        string alphabetArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        //char[][] alphabetArray = new Char[5,5] {{"A","B","C","D","E"},{"F","G","H","I/J", "K"},{"L","M","N","O","P"},{"Q","R","S","T","U"},{"V","W","X","Y","Z"}};
        // "parse" user input from key textbox
        string userCipherKey = ChipherTextBox.Text;

        // "parse" user input from message textbox
        string messageForEncryption = InputRichTextBox.Text;

        // insert cipher key into alphabet string array begining at the 0 location
        string combinedStrings = alphabetArray.Insert(0, userCipherKey);

        // remove duplicate letters from newly created array
        string arrayWithDuplicateCharsRemoved = ""; // localized decleration of new array name

        foreach (char value in combinedStrings)
        {
            // See if character is in the result already.
            if (arrayWithDuplicateCharsRemoved.IndexOf(value) == -1)
            {
                // Append to the result.
                arrayWithDuplicateCharsRemoved += value;
            }
        }

        // convert char values back to a string
        string encryptionArray = arrayWithDuplicateCharsRemoved.ToString();


        // turn the new string into a 2d array
        //char[] encryptionArray = removedDuplicateCharsFromArray.ToCharArray();
        string encryptedMessage;


        for (int i = 0; i < encryptionArray.Length; i++)
        {
            encryptedMessage = messageForEncryption.Replace(messageForEncryption, encryptionArray);
        }

        string messageOutput = encryptedMessage.ToString();

        return OutputRichTextBox.Text = messageOutput.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: The 2d array is commented out. Can you edit this to reflect your question?

Comment: what do you mean? i edited out the 2d array because it wont allow me to insert the cipher key characters in. so i've been using a regular string.

Comment: Well, if your question details the swapping of elements in a 2d array, the code should too. Are you wanting to figure out how to do it with an array or string?

Comment: at this point i don't care, either way, what ever works. i tried both and failed. i just don't know enough to know how to do it and all i get is trolled when i ask how.

Comment: It may be because of your approach to asking. When you say "I don't care" it comes across as just wanting someone to write it for you rather than help you with a specific problem. I'd chose which one you want and edit the question.

Comment: I've asked specific questions many times, not on this site. Mostly reddit. Believe me asking for help is a last resort because I know how hostile people are when others ask questions. At this point I truly don't care. I've been through all the google searches and documentations I can find.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about what happens on other sites. Do your best to meet the standards here and you'll be fine. Over time you'll get better at asking and searching. [For example.](https://www.google.com/search?q=playfair+cipher+implementation+in+c%23&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS700US700&oq=C%23+playfair+cypher+implem&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i58j0.11606j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)